Referencing a Mediawiki uploaded image in Vector.CSS
I see on some other Mediawiki's, like Minecraft, that in their Vector.CSS they use:
--vector-tabs: url('filepath://Vector-tabs.png');

and that seems to autotranslate to the complete path in the downloaded CSS:
--vector-tabs: url(/images/Vector-tabs.png?0ceb5);

but when I use that on my Mediawiki, I just get back the same text
Vector.css:
--base-background: url('filepath://AdventureRoadBackground.png');

returns:
--base-background: url(filepath://AdventureRoadBackground.png);

I checked, and File:AdventureRoadBackground.png does indeed exist.
Is there a hook that needs to be written, a setting to be flipped, or an extension to install to get this translation to work?
MediaWiki   1.40.0
www.cubieversewiki.com
